# Maintain website layout during resize (resize all elements at the same time with javascript?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My layout is a mess. It works just fine given a certain resolution and I've decided to spread this same layout vertically on mobile clients to avoid further complications. The problem comes when resizing the desktop client. **Not every element takes part on shrinking / expanding** and the whole website stays desfigurated. **I've tried keeping it all via '%' in width and height but does not work as it should anyway**

- How could the layout integrity be kept the same?
- How exactly do experienced frontend developers react to user changes in the layout and/or different screen resolutions?

**Is there any library that expands and shrinks every element on resize?** Keeping harmony between width, height, font-size, whatever. I hardly believe no one has ever developed such a thing like this... Tyvm for your help...

Comment: Learn about fluid grid column layouts (eg, Bootstrap), or use Flex.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have one layout for every screen size, even if the elements are resized accordingly. Once you start adding in mobile screens the UX plummets with a layout intended for bigger screens. Bootstrap is the most popular solution for a responsive layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use css so you can use relative layout?

Answer (score 1):

Using media queries in your CSS file will help better.
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: what about using vm units? I notice it keeps the layout in most of the cases. Would this be considered a good alternative in my case? I'm not really understanding media queries...

Comment: Yes, good comment +1.  For vm units, i like using the viewport meta tag in my head, and depending on the circumstances, i use %'s or vw/vh for sizes.  Sometimes i use rem for fonts on for mobile.  Don't know why though, it looks good on my device

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything in the same proporsion when resizing a webpage I always use either % og em/rem.

ex:

```
width: 100%;
```

or:

```
width: 45em;
```

This way, when users change the zom, the design keeps itself in the same proporsion.